# Error while importing keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, importerror

I used `from keras.layers import dot` and got this error in return:

```
c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     17         try:
---> 18             fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
     19         except ImportError:

c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\imp.py in find_module(name, path)
    295     else:
--> 296         raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
    297 

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     19         except ImportError:
---> 20             import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
     21             return _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      2 try:
----> 3     from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
      4 except ImportError:

c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 

c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     51 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 52   raise ImportError(msg)
     53 

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-884a93be26a0> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.layers import dot

c:\users\prashasti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      4 except ImportError:
      5     raise ImportError(
----> 6         'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
      7         'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')
      8 

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

I upgraded tensorflow. reinstalled it too but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I have CUDA 10.0 and cuDNN 7.6.4
I also getting this below error

*ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`*

What I did was first uninstall everything like no python, no anaconda, no virtual env.

Then perform below steps:

1. Install anaconda win 64 with python 3.7 as one package
2. After Anaconda install, need to set the path C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Scripts
3. update pip
4. Conda update
5. conda create -n tf20 python=3.7
6. pip install numpy
7. pip install "tensorflow>=1.15,<2.0"
8. pip install "tensorflow-gpu>=1.15,<2.0" (If GPU support needed)
9. pip install keras (installed with latest 2.4.2)
10. pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub
11. pip install keras==2.2.4 (downgraded to 2.2.4)

Now keras running with tensorflow 1.15
Probably you can do pip install keras==2.2.4 in step 9 and remove step 11.
Just try once above steps from step 2 onwards before uninstall everthing. If that works that you can save your time.
Good Luck :)

Please do let me know if this worked for you.

-Thanks

Comment: It didn't work for me. So many issues with installing tensorflow, how is that possible.