# Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher

Tags: tensorflow, keras, installation

I want to use keras with the code shown below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
df = DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end=datetime.now())
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow
```

I have both keras 2.4.3 and tensorflow 2.2.0 installed in anaconda environment. I uninstalled and installed jupiter notebook but it didn't help.

Comment: When you're using keras with tensorflow, you shoudl use the tensorflow.keras package instead

Comment: Update the question with the code that is causing the error.

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks for writing. There is no package tensorflow.keras in Anaconda environment. I tried installing keras-gpu, but I got the following message  UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Comment: anaconda's tensorflow project has already this package

Comment: I solved the problem by simply installing different versions of keras (2.3.1 instead of 2.4.3) and tensorflow (2.0.0 instead of 2.2.0).

Comment: @Vivi - use `import tensorflow as tf; tf.keras` instead of `import keras`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465620/error-keras-requires-tensorflow-2-2-or-higher)

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Solved the problem by simply installing different versions of keras
> (2.3.1 instead of 2.4.3) and tensorflow (2.0.0 instead of 2.2.0). Keras are integrated with Tensorflow from 2.3 onwards, you can upgrade tensorflow to latest version and use module `tf.keras` (paraphrased from Vivi and jakub)

To run code in TF 2.4 is as shown below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
df = DataReader('AAPL', data_source='yahoo', start='2012-01-01', end=datetime.now())
```