# No module named 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

**Below the code**

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format ='retina'

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
```

**below the Error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      2 try:
----> 3     from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
      4 except ImportError:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-943507dd87a6> in <module>
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('config', "InlineBackend.figure_format ='retina'")
      7 
----> 8 from keras.models import Sequential
      9 from keras.layers import Dense
     10 from keras.optimizers import SGD

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      4 except ImportError:
      5     raise ImportError(
----> 6         'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
      7         'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')
      8 

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow
```

**Note:`** I think, the main problem is Tensorflow version. I used somes command and that's are bellow,

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

**and I also used the below command**

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```

But it don't works , Please help for solve the error.

Comment: print(tf.__version__)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need update TensorFlow. You can try with

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

or, if you use gpu version

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
```

If doesn't solve your issue, you can also try with `2.2.0` version.

For more details, in this issue [follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465620/error-keras-requires-tensorflow-2-2-or-higher)

Comment: Ashraful Alom brother, still now it's show the same error

Comment: Hey Imdadul, close and open Python editor/shell again, it worked here. For me I got the same error, I updated the tensorflow and the error was on still. Then I closed Python and opened again. it worked!

Comment: I am experiencing the same error, I dont have the option for tf 2.0.0 or 2.2.0
I have from 2.8 to 2.12.
It works great on my virtual env from my jupyter notebook but when I try to copy the code to a regular `.py` file on my desktop I cant run it.

Answer (score 10):

you need to update the version of your TensorFlow. For me, 2.2.0 solved the problem. I also checked with the higher versions and worked ok.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

or

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0
```