# Error: cannot import name 'StringLookup' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I can import preprocessing:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
```

But I can't import or use any of the layers inside it:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import StringLookup

ImportError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-4f042fcbcc66> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import StringLookup

ImportError: cannot import name 'StringLookup' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' (/home/julie/miniconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/__init__.py)
```

I found several resources citing versions as the issue. My environment is running:

- Tensorflow 2.2.0
- Keras 2.4.3

Both were installed through conda.

Comment: import tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup gives the same error.

Comment: Have a look [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542803/no-module-named-tensorflow-keras-layers-experimental-preprocessing)

Comment: You need to update tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu. Which version of tensorflow do you have in your conda environment ?

Comment: tensorflow is 2.2.0. I found several resources pointing to tensorflow needing to be at least 2.1, but I'm already there.

Comment: which python version your environment has?

Comment: I have Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 0):

It seems your python is `python 3.9`.
Make sure your python version is `Python 3.5–3.8`.
check your version by `$ python3 --version`.

Reinstall python 3.8 as tensorflow does not support for a higher version of python. Use the command line to install. `conda install python=3.8`.

Comment: I have Python 3.8.5

Comment: Then other packages might have a conflict with TensorFlow. Try the following: make a separate temporary conda environment, install python=3.8, and install TensorFlow and check whether it works. I did the same and it works.

Comment: I just did that - installed python and tensorflow from anaconda (and only those two).  Now I have some of the layers, but not all.  I still can't run 
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import StringLookup.

But I can run 
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import StringLookup

Comment: I think there is a typo in your last comment.

Comment: My apologies, I still can't run from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import StringLookup.   I can run from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomFlip

Comment: which python IDE you are using? could you try it directly in the terminal?

Comment: That's what I did with the new environment.  I created the new environment with python=3.8.0, then installed tensorflow with conda install -c anaconda tensorflow.  Then used python directly in the terminal to attempt several imports.

Comment: Bingo ! Install TensorFlow with following : `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: ran into AVX issues with Tensorflow.  So did the install from source and compiled my own whl for tensorflow.  Now it works! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me is:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.6.0
pip install keras==2.6.0
```

By bringing both tf and keras to 2.6.0