# Keras does not load because cannot find TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Running Anaconda and installed:
Keras = 2.4.3
TensorFlow = 2.4.0

However, when importing Keras - I get "Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher".

Tried uninstalling/installing - did not help.

Any idea?

Comment: have you seen this one? -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465620/error-keras-requires-tensorflow-2-2-or-higher

Comment: Yes it does!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

to install an upgraded and compatible `TensorFlow` version in your system.