# ModuleNotFoundError: tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection, object-detection-api

Even though I have tensorflow installed in the venv at version 2.12.0 it kinda does not have  tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing. I tried to install the object-detection API and I am still struggling to get it work. Here is what I got as an error message when I tried to run the
test file python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py. The second photo shows you what I got when I tried to run the command python -m pip install .

Some stuff works but like I said I am not able to make the test file work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnbFP.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xHdh.png)

I already did install visual studio 2017 because I got an error that object detection needed that and I also did everything what was written in the installement guide here https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tf-models-install-coco

I tried that already the whole da so I would be really happy if somebody could help me:)

Comment: You are using the incorrect imports, do not use tensorflow.python.keras, use tensorflow.keras directly

Answer (score -1):

You need update your TensorFlow -

```
pip install tensorflow==2.7.0
```

for gpu version -

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.7.0
```

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465620/error-keras-requires-tensorflow-2-2-or-higher)

You can also to this [link](https://tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) for more details

Comment: then I get an comment with ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0

Comment: thats because its more older version and its not supported. You can try installing version - `2.5.0`. I have also modified the Answer

Comment: then I got this error message :/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.5.0 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0)

Comment: what is the python or pip version you are using ?

Comment: I am using pip 23.1.2 and python 3.11

Comment: Oh, tensorflow `2.5.0` is not compatible with these version. And from the documentation, it seems like `2.7.0` is the first version. try installing this version.

Comment: here is the links - 1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.7.0.

2. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu